# Test rail API binding - unrecognized response code (308)

Tags: java, automation, testrail

Test rail API binding - unrecognized response code (308)

I am new at test rail, and I starting implementing the automation infrastructure that will sync the automation test results to the Test Rail server.
I am using Java, and here is the code snippet...

```
package com.util.testrail;

import com.util.log.ColorLog;
import com.util.testrail.APIClient;
import com.util.testrail.APIException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        APIClient client = new APIClient("http://ect.testrail.io/");
        client.setUser("asih@evercompliant.com");
        client.setPassword("asi1234$");

        Map data = new HashMap();
        data.put("status_id", new Integer(1));
        data.put("comment", "This test worked fine!");
        JSONObject r = (JSONObject) client.sendPost("add_result_for_case/1/1", 
        data);

        JSONObject c = (JSONObject) client.sendGet("get_case/1");
        System.out.println(c.get("title"));


    }
}
```

The exception I am getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.util.testrail.APIException: TestRail API return HTTP 308 (No additional error message received)
        at com.util.testrail.APIClient.sendRequest(APIClient.java:159)
        at com.util.testrail.APIClient.sendPost(APIClient.java:115)
        at com.util.testrail.Program.main(Program.java:21)
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51632', transport: 'socket'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually that you tried to use http:// instead of https://, resulting in a redirect. Make sure you use the correct HTTPS address of: https://seleniumautomation.testrail.net/

Comment: Agreed, this also points to the same point @Chris has made. 
https://discuss.gurock.com/t/308-redirection-when-using-python-2-7-adding-ssl-certificate-for-https-support/9999